# how to change 3d object position on android java arcore

Tags: android-studio, arcore

I have to change the 3d object position vertically and horizontally

I am developing a demo android app that scan keyboard image and replace a 3d keyboard and put a black switch on that keyboard .I have succeeded to do it . But I couldn't change that switch's position .I have attached a screenshot and marked 2 place where I want place black switch(round button).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th4NG.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ArFragment arFragment;
    boolean shouldAddModel = true;
    private TransformableNode nodeParent, subNodeTrans;
    private final boolean useSingleImage = false;
    private boolean isSwitchEnable =true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arFragment = (CustomArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sceneform_fragment);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdateFrame);



    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) {
        Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

        Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);

        for (AugmentedImage augmentedImage : augmentedImages) {
            if (augmentedImage.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                if (/*augmentedImage.getName().equals("mykey") &&*/ shouldAddModel) {
                    //5.5f
                    //3.01f
                    placSubeObject(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), R.raw.switchee);
                    placeObject(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), R.raw.keyboard);

                    shouldAddModel = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void placeObject(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, int uri) {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(arFragment.getContext(), uri)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable))
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                            //Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Error:" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return null;
                        }

                );
    }

    private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Renderable renderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        nodeParent = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
  /*      nodeParent.setOnTouchListener(new Node.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "key board click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arFragment.getTransformationSystem().setSelectionVisualizer(new BlanckSelectionVisualizer());
                // remove the white circle at the bottom of the model?
                return false;
            }
        });*/
        arFragment.getTransformationSystem().setSelectionVisualizer(new BlanckSelectionVisualizer());

        nodeParent.setRenderable(renderable);
        nodeParent.setParent(anchorNode);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
       nodeParent.getScaleController().setMaxScale(5.5f);
       nodeParent.getScaleController().setMinScale(3.01f);
        nodeParent.setLocalRotation( Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0f), 180));//rotate the 3d module
    }


    public boolean setupAugmentedImagesDb(Config config, Session session) {
        AugmentedImageDatabase augmentedImageDatabase;

        if(useSingleImage)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = loadAugmentedImage();
            if (bitmap == null) {
                return false;
            }
            augmentedImageDatabase = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
            augmentedImageDatabase.addImage("tiger", bitmap);
        }else{
            try (InputStream is = getAssets().open("myimages.imgdb")) {
                augmentedImageDatabase = AugmentedImageDatabase.deserialize(session, is);
                shouldAddModel =true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IO exception loading augmented image database.", e);
                return false;
            }
        }
        config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(augmentedImageDatabase);
        return true;
    }

    private Bitmap loadAugmentedImage() {
        try (InputStream is = getAssets().open("mykey.jpg")) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ImageLoad", "IO Exception", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        removePlaneDiscover();
    }

    private void removePlaneDiscover(){
        if (arFragment != null) {
            // hiding the plane discovery
            arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide();
            arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);
            arFragment.getArSceneView().getPlaneRenderer().setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void placSubeObject(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, int uri) {
        var posison=anchor.getPose().extractTranslation();
        Log.d(TAG, "local iscaler is x "+ posison.getRotationQuaternion());
        posison = Pose.makeTranslation(posison.tx(),posison.ty(),posison.tz()+.05f);

        Anchor anchor_ = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(posison);



        Log.d(TAG, "local iscaler is x "+ posison.tx()+ " y "+posison.ty() + " z "+posison.tz()+"");
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(arFragment.getContext(), uri)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addSubNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor_, modelRenderable))
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                            //Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Error:" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return null;
                        }

                );
    }

    private void addSubNodeToScene(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Renderable renderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
         subNodeTrans = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        subNodeTrans.setOnTouchListener(new Node.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(HitTestResult hitTestResult, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(isSwitchEnable)
                    showDialog();
                arFragment.getTransformationSystem().setSelectionVisualizer(new BlanckSelectionVisualizer());
                // remove the white circle at the bottom of the model?
                return false;
            }
        });

        subNodeTrans.setRenderable(renderable);
        subNodeTrans.setParent(anchorNode);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        subNodeTrans.getScaleController().setMaxScale(0.5f);
        subNodeTrans.getScaleController().setMinScale(0.05f);
        subNodeTrans.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 270f));
        Vector3 vector3 = nodeParent.getLocalScale();
        
    }
    private void showDialog(){
        isSwitchEnable =false;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("User has clicked the button")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Whatever...
                        isSwitchEnable = true;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
    }
}
```